# javascript onsubmit returns two different values in the same call

Tags: javascript, html, validation

the validation function

```
     function validateForm(){
                var els;
                els = document.getElementById('name');
                if(els.value == ''){
                    console.log(0);
                    alert('Ai uitat sa completezi numele');
                    return false;
                }
                els = document.getElementsByClassName('education');
                [].forEach.call(els, function (el){
                    if(el.value == ''){
                        alert('Ai uitat unul sau mai multe campuri la educatie');
                        console.log(1);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                console.log(2)
                return false;
            }
```

the form

```
<form onsubmit="return validateForm()" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ URL::to('/admin/people/') }}" method="POST" id="myForm">
```

I have dynamic html generated, so im doing a javascript validation besides the server side validation so the user won't lose that dynamic generated html when the page reloads.
The problem here is that it outputs both 1 and 2 (submitting the form if i change the third return to true), which is extremely strange...
There are no errors displayed in the console too

If it enters the first if, it only outputs 0 there,so i'm guessing it's something caused by the loop?

Comment: I think the `return false` after `console.log(1)` only breaks out of the forEach block/loop, and then it reaches `console.log(2)`

Comment: and how can i stop the execution there?

Comment: i figured it out, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
            [].forEach.call(els, function (el){
                if(el.value == ''){
                    alert('Ai uitat unul sau mai multe campuri la educatie');
                    console.log(1);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

causes a return from a different scope than your main function. The only two possible log values from your main function (while intercepting your submit) are "0" or "2".

The logging of the value of "1" happens in a completely different scope and thread. And `console.log` doesn't care which thread it comes from. It just logs in the order it receives data.

Comment: yep, thanks a lot, i tortured my brain almost 3 hours on this

Comment: Believe me I've been there. Javascript can be confusing at times.

Answer (score 0):

The `return false` inside the forEach has no effect, the processing will continue after looping through the whole array
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

use a plain loop instead:

```
for (let i = 0, len = els.length; i < len; i++) {
  let el = els[i];
  if(el.value == ''){
    alert('Ai uitat unul sau mai multe campuri la educatie');
    console.log(1);
    return false;
  }
}
```